# "Need to" or "have"? Politeness

Tags: phrase-request

I want to know how to reply when I want to check it would be proper and right  in a polite manner. I'd like to ask whether I understood well.

For example,

> Do I **need** to hold the figure in both policies?
>
> Do I **have** to hold the figure in both policies?

Otherwise, could you advise me if there is better sentence?

For example, I mean if I receive email at work as including "please reserve USD 10,000" and there is 2 policies: A policy and B policy. I think the figure need to be applied both policies. In that case, I want to know I want to make sure it is correct what I think in polite and tender way.

Answer (score 1):

*Need* and *have* are both polite in this situation. *Need* is a little more formal, but no one is likely to notice a difference.

We would probably use more clear and specific language, however:

> Do I need/have to hold $10,000 for each policy, a total of $20,000, or is it $10,000?

I am familiar with American Standard English. I think British people could also say either of these, but might be more likely to say *Have I got to ...?*

Americans could also use *got,* but I think it would be much less common.

If you want to be more formal, you might ask, *Is the requirement to hold ....?* That is quite formal and may sound odd or old-fashioned to some, if you are asking verbally. Since it's in writing, it would be normal, and probably the best choice, especially if you don't know the person well, or if they wrote to you in a formal manner.

If you put these ideas together, a standard business email might read:

> Thank you for your email of January 1st.
>
> I'd like to clarify the amount of the reserve requirement.
>
> Do I need to reserve $10,000 for each policy ($20,000), or is $10,000 the total requirement for both?